# ServiceException: 401 Unauthorized WebHook callback channel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, google, gsutil

Can anyone help me with issue on setting up "Object Change Notification". I am trying to execute "

```
gsutil notification watchbucket https://<my_project_id>.appspot.com/ gs://glrs_test_deepshikha
```

It is giving error :

```
ServiceException: 401 Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://<my_project_id>.appspot.com/
```

I have successfully verified the domain as an owner. able to load file using gsutil cp. But, gsutil watchbucket is not working.please help

Comment: Can you include the output of https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/webmasters.sites.list and a screenshot of https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification to help see if there is a problem with the domain verification?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but anyway I'll let here an answer in case someone is interested.

Object Change Notifications are a legacy feature that allowed to add a *watcher* to a Storage Bucket pointing to a HTTPS url that would receive information about the object changes. The information about these notifications could be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification).

One of the requirements to use this feature is that the URI ob the webhook needs to be verified for ownership as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorization). From the error message it seems that was actually the reason.

Nowadays the preferable approach to obtain notifications regarding object changes would be to enable PubSub notifications which are easier to set up and more scalable and cost-effective. More information in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#overview)